# How to install ngen dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, ngen

I'm using ngen to install native image of an exe but i need also to install their dependencies when i try

```
ngen install c:\myfiles\MyLib.dll /ExeConfig:c:\myapps\MyApp.exe
```

I get the following errors

```
Could not load file or assembly xxx  or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

I'm using theses dll with Assembly.load

How i can resolve this problem ?